# Calculate the probability that the total is greater than 45?

Tags: probability

I have seen this question around on the web but never seen a sufficient answer...
10 six-sided dice are thrown and the total number of spots showing is noted. Calculate the probability that the total is greater than 45?

I calculated that the mean is 35 and the standard deviation is 5.91 for the 10 throws in total. From there I'm a bit lost.

Comment: One can hold one's nose and use the normal approximation. With continuity correction it might not be too bad. But $10$ is too small for reliability.

Comment: I may be miscomputing, but I think the standard deviation is about $5.4$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm less skeptical than Andre about the normal approximation in this case-- I think it might work out well.  Let's see.

For the normal approximation with correction for continuity, we want $P(X > 45.5)$, where $X$ has a Normal distribution with mean 35 and standard deviation 5.400617. (Andre is correct, your original calculation of the standard deviation is wrong.)  This is equivalent to $P(Z > 1.94422)$ where $Z$ is a N(0,1) random variable, which yields a probability of 0.025934.

For an exact calculation, I'll use ordinary power series generating functions. There are 6^10  possible outcomes with 10 dice, each of which we assume is equally likely. If $S$ is the sum of the dice, then we want $P(S > 45) = 1 - P(S \le 45)$.  Let $a_r$ be the number of ways to roll a total of $r$ with the dice, and define $f(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a^r x^r$ (actually a finite sum).  Then it's easy to see that
$$f(x) = (x + x^2 + \dots + x^6)^{10} = x^{10} \left( \frac{1-x^6}{1-x} \right) ^ {10}$$
If $g(x)$ is the generating function of $S$, then $g(x) = (1-x)^{-1} f(x)$, so by the Binomial Theorem
$$g(x) = x^{10} (1-x^6) ^ {10} (1-x)^{-11} = x^{10} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{10} (-1)^i \binom{10}{i} x^{6i} \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{10+j}{10} x^j$$
The coefficient of $x^{45}$ in this expression, which I'll denote as $[x^{45}]$, is the number of ways to roll 45 or less, and we can deduce it from the previous equation:
$$[x^{45}] = \sum_{i=0}^{5} (-1)^i \binom{10}{i} \binom{45-6i}{10} = 58,939,530$$
Then $$P(S > 45) = 1 - P(S \le 45) = 1- \frac{[x^{45}]}{6^{10}} = 0.025247$$ so the normal approximation worked pretty well in this case.